# In R, Are valid the given coefficients of glm()?

Tags: r, glm, coefficients

I got in R after glm():

```
Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
D_N    -1.405e+05  3.451e+04  -4.072 0.000166 ***
D_q     1.405e+05  3.451e+04   4.072 0.000166 ***
D_Rho  -9.368e-01  2.455e-01  -3.815 0.000375 ***
Dn_N    4.958e+05  1.265e+05   3.919 0.000271 ***
Dn_q   -4.958e+05  1.265e+05  -3.919 0.000271 ***
Dn_Rho  3.777e+00  5.567e-01   6.785  1.3e-08 ***
```

The question is: The coefficient of D_N and D_q or Dn_N and Dn_q have the same values but with opposite sign.

**Is this a valid model? Still both coefficients are the same with opposite sign?**

More info: D_N and D_q or Dn_N and Dn_q in the database have the same values but with opposite sign.

Comment: If you mean that `D_N = -D_q` and `Dn_N = -Dn_q` in your data set, then see [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity).

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more about how you fitted the model and clarify whether @MikaelJagan's guess is correct? The part I don't understand is that normally `glm()` would *automatically* remove collinear variables, e.g. try `set.seed(101); n <- 100; dd <- data.frame(y = rpois(n, lambda = 2), D_N = runif(n)); dd <- transform(dd, D_q = -1*D_N) m <- glm(y ~ D_N + D_q, family = poisson, data = dd); summary(m)` and you'll see that the `D_q` coefficient is `NA`.

Comment: @BenBolker I'm guessing their data frame is more like `transform(dd, D_q = D_N + rnorm(D_N, 0, 1e-06))`, with enough fuzz to throw `glm` off the scent. That would yield coefficients with opposite sign. (OK - I'll be patient now and stop guessing.)

Comment: Maybe, but I don't get quite the behaviour above (tried a few different "fuzz" levels). Voted to close "needs clarity/details" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following to verify the model after getting what you just showed:

```
fit2 <- glm(Y~I(D_q-D_N)+I(Dn_N-Dn_q)+D_Rho+Dn_Rho)
```

Perhaps then, you could compare both models using Akaike's coefficient:

```
AIC(yourfit, fit2)
```

And draw conclussions... Only you know if that makes physical sense... Also, check if the independent variables present some sort of colinerity...